# Read xmlhttp object

Tags: javascript

I make a javascript query to the bing API. Using the XML-http function in javascript for that.

If I print

```
xmlhttp.responseText;
```

it correctly returns an object like this:

```
{
   "d":{
      "results":[
         {
            "__metadata":{
               "uri":"Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?Query=\u0027weltall\u0027&$skip=0&$top=1",
               "type":"WebResult"
            },
            "ID":"ec45ae51-c52b-4172-b64e-97f0db106110",
            "Title":"Universum – Wikipedia",
            "Description":"Universum, Weltall und Weltraum. Das Wort „Universum“ wurde im 17. Jahrhundert von Philipp von Zesen durch das Wort „Weltall“ eingedeutscht.",
            "DisplayUrl":"/wiki/Universum",
            "Url":"/wiki/Universum"
         },
         {
            "__metadata":{
               "uri":"Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?Query=\u0027weltall\u0027&$skip=1&$top=1",
               "type":"WebResult"
            },
            "ID":"8703f1c8-f3b7-48b0-b2cf-e33071b5006e",
            "Title":"Weltall - Wissenschaft - SPIEGEL ONLINE",
            "Description":"Nachrichten aus der Wissenschaft über Mensch und Technik, Natur und Weltall. Aktuelle Reportagen, Analysen, Interviews.",
            "DisplayUrl":"/wissenschaft/weltall",
            "Url":"spiegel.de/wissenschaft/weltall/"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

So far so good. But when I try to access individual properties of said object, nothing gets returned:

```
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = xmlhttp.d.results.uri[1];
```

There seems to be an error in that line. I thought of the object like a database with nested columns (the .d.results.uri part) and rows (the [1] part).

Comment: `responseText` as its name implies is not an object but a string. You need to JSON.parse() it. Also, you are assigning `xmlhttp.d.results.uri[1]` but even if responsText was an object it should be `xmlhttp.responsText.d.results.uri[1]`

Comment: `responseText` is a string, not an object. You need to JSON.parse it first. On a different note, please take a few moments to format your question properly next time, it's really not that hard.

Comment: @marekful, why don't you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xmlhttp` object contains response data in it's `responseText` property. Since you are dealing with JSON you also have to parse it using javascripts `JSON.parse()` thus, you should be able to get your desired response data using this snippet:

```
    data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Also, I don't think that you are trying to access the right node, because `d.results.uri[1]` doesn't exist in the json you have shown us.

Try visualizing your json. I usually use [this](http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm). It allows you to get your desired node by simply clicking on it and copying it's path.